# How can I sum elements in a html table after filtering by class?

Tags: javascript, html

I created the following table by defining different classes in javascript (the table is actually bigger but I reduced it to 3 lines for a better comprehension).

[image]

I type manually the inputs in the first column and it calculates A, B, C and SUM.

A = 5 * input

B = 4 * input

C = 3 * input

SUM = A + B + C

Total SUM  =should be in this example 36 + 24 + 60 (actually there are more rows in my column) but I don't know exactly  how to automatize the job. I am trying something in this direction but it does not do the job:

```
forEach ({

row.querySelector(".total").value +- =  (Number(row.querySelector(".sum"))
```

Here is the code of the table and how I generate the values:

```
<table class="egt" bgcolor="Olive">
  <! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>INPUT</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>SUM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <! --TERCERA LINEA -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="fuel" style="text-align:center">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="A" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="B" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="C" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="sum" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="fuel" style="text-align:center">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="A" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="B" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="C" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="sum" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="fuel" style="text-align:center">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="A" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="B" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="C" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="sum" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <! --ULTIMA LINEA -->
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" align="right">Total SUM = </th>
    <td><input class="total" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
let rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
[...rows].forEach(row => {
   row.querySelector(".fuel").addEventListener("input", (event) => {
     calculate(row)
   })
})


function calculate(row) {

let fuel = row.querySelector(".fuel").value;
row.querySelector(".A").value = (5 * fuel);
row.querySelector(".B").value = (4 * fuel);
row.querySelector(".C").value = (3 * fuel);
row.querySelector(".sum").value = (Number(row.querySelector(".A").value) + Number(row.querySelector(".B").value) + Number(row.querySelector(".C").value)); 

}
```

Thanks for your advise!

Comment: `[...querySelectorAll('.sum')].reduce((a, v) => a += v.value,0)`

Comment: I have just tried row.querySelector(".total").value = [...querySelectorAll('.sum')].reduce((a, v) => a += v.value,0) and it does not do the job.

Comment: **Unrelated:** `NodeList` offers `forEach()` without using spread.

Comment: What are your filtering criterias? How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to simplify your example a bit. Selected all the elements we're going to need at the start of the code and then attached the event listener to your inputs. When input value changes, we're recalculating the sum of the entire row and the total sum afterwards.

```js
const totalSum = document.querySelector('.total');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel');
const sums = document.querySelectorAll('.sum');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('input', event => {
    recalculateRowSum(input);
    recalculateTotalSum();
  });
});

function recalculateRowSum(input) {
  const row = input.parentNode.parentNode;
  
  const a = input.value * 5;
  const b = input.value * 4;
  const c = input.value * 3;
  const sum = a + b + c;

  row.querySelector('.A').value = a;
  row.querySelector('.B').value = b;
  row.querySelector('.C').value = c;
  row.querySelector('.sum').value = sum;
}

function recalculateTotalSum() {
  totalSum.value = [...sums].reduce((total, current) => total += +current.value, 0);
}
```

```html
<table class="egt" bgcolor="Olive">
  
  <! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>INPUT</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>SUM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <! --TERCERA LINEA -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="fuel" style="text-align:center">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="A" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="B" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="C" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="sum" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="fuel" style="text-align:center">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="A" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="B" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="C" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="sum" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="fuel" style="text-align:center">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="A" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="B" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="C" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="sum" type="number" style="text-align:center" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <! --ULTIMA LINEA -->
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="right">Total SUM = </th>
      <td><input class="total" type="number" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

add new function to update total value

```
let rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
[...rows].forEach(row => {
    row.querySelector(".fuel").addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        calculate(row)
    })
})


function calculate(row) {

    let fuel = row.querySelector(".fuel").value;
    row.querySelector(".A").value = (5 * fuel);
    row.querySelector(".B").value = (4 * fuel);
    row.querySelector(".C").value = (3 * fuel);
    row.querySelector(".sum").value = (Number(row.querySelector(".A").value) + Number(row.querySelector(".B").value) + Number(row.querySelector(".C").value));
    calculateSum();
}

function calculateSum() {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("tbody .sum");
    let total = 0;
    [...elements].forEach(ele => {
        total += parseFloat(ele.value) || 0;
    })
    document.querySelector("tbody .total").value = total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's clean it up:

```js
const setup = () => {
    

  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel');

  [...rows].forEach(row => row.addEventListener('input', onInput));
}

const calculateSum = () => {
    const sums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.sum')].map(input => Number.parseInt(input.value));
  const result = sums.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value);
  document.querySelector('.total').value = result;
}

const onInput = event => {
    const input = event.target;
  const currentIndex = input.dataset.rowIndex;
  
  const fuel = Number.parseInt(input.value, 10);
  const [A, B, C] = [(5 * fuel), (4 * fuel), (3 * fuel)]
  const sum = A + B + C;
  
  document.querySelector(`[data-row-index="${currentIndex}"].A`).value = A;
  document.querySelector(`[data-row-index="${currentIndex}"].B`).value = B;
  document.querySelector(`[data-row-index="${currentIndex}"].C`).value = C;
  document.querySelector(`[data-row-index="${currentIndex}"].sum`).value = sum;
  
  calculateSum();
  
}

//load
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```css
tbody input[type="number"] {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="egt" bgcolor="Olive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>INPUT</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>SUM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="fuel" data-row-index="0" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="A" data-row-index="0" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="B" data-row-index="0" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="C" data-row-index="0" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="sum" data-row-index="0" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="fuel" data-row-index="1" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="A" data-row-index="1" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="B" data-row-index="1" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="C" data-row-index="1" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="sum" data-row-index="1" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="fuel" data-row-index="2" type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="A" data-row-index="2" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="B" data-row-index="2" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="C" data-row-index="2" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="sum" data-row-index="2" type="number" disabled>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="right">Total SUM = </th>
      <td><input class="total" type="number" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: A small note with the result. Currently, all values are threatened as integers instead of decimals (`Number.parseInt(..., 10)`). If you want to convert them to a decimal use `Number(...)` instead.

Comment: You can improve your HTML by including `min` & `step` to make it harder for the user to inject negative & non-integer values into your input.